# Python install creator

Tags: python, windows, installation

Hi i want to build an install creator for my programs in Python.

I have made code for the information gathering, PATHS, FILES, PICS etc.

Now i need to:
Compress the files for the program.
make a config file with install paths ect.
make code for the INSTALLER (i have that to)
   Finally i need to "pack" it all in an .exe file that will run the first window in my INSTALLER CODE, so that it will work as my own custom made installer.

Does anybody have any idea how to go about this EASY??

My biggest problem is to collect it all in ONE .exe file that will run my windows(TK code) and of course install my program when clicked...

I have a few ideas how to go about it, BUT in my head these ideas seem to be BIG and NOT EASY, so need ideas for easier solutions.

Update. If i have a program build in python(Tkinter) that will gather the information and save this info as a config file. Then i can build a program that can read this information and extract files ect. accordingly to the info. But how will i combine these configfiles/programs in ONE .exe file that when clicked will run MY program and then accordingly extract my files to the paths in config file. And last use my own icon for the single .exe

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have everything in one exe file, its code needs to be aware of it's content and extract them. This is a problem that has been solved by various tools, eg. see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers) and its answers.